# In BigQuery, how to sort values separately for each column

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to sort each column separately in a table in bigquery? We have a table of statistics and we would like to sort each column separately within partitions. We have 3 stats `stat1`, `stat2`, `stat3` and `gender` is our partition key:

```
with
  stats as (
    select 'male' as gender, .60 as stat1, 23 as stat2, .10 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .62 as stat1, 28 as stat2, .12 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .57 as stat1, 21 as stat2, .16 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .51 as stat1, 18 as stat2, .14 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .53 as stat1, 17 as stat2, .18 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .46 as stat1, 31 as stat2, .08 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .49 as stat1, 32 as stat2, .07 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .55 as stat1, 40 as stat2, .23 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .68 as stat1, 41 as stat2, .33 as stat3 union all
    select 'male' as gender, .56 as stat1, 36 as stat2, .32 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .80 as stat1, 32 as stat2, .42 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .82 as stat1, 24 as stat2, .43 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .73 as stat1, 26 as stat2, .33 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .85 as stat1, 27 as stat2, .55 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .91 as stat1, 29 as stat2, .53 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .88 as stat1, 13 as stat2, .51 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .86 as stat1, 38 as stat2, .49 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .77 as stat1, 35 as stat2, .40 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .74 as stat1, 15 as stat2, .58 as stat3 union all
    select 'female' as gender, .95 as stat1, 17 as stat2, .59 as stat3
  ),

  -- we create rank columns
  stats_with_ranks as (
    select
      *
      ,row_number() over (partition by gender) as rank
      ,rank() over (partition by gender order by stat1 desc) as stat1rk
      ,rank() over (partition by gender order by stat2 desc) as stat2rk
      ,rank() over (partition by gender order by stat3 desc) as stat3rk
    from stats
  )

select * from stats_with_ranks where gender = 'female' order by rank asc
```

[image]

This is not the correct table for our problem. We'd like each metric to be sorted within its own column such that its values correspond to the singular `rank` column. For example, the highest value for each of `stat1`, `stat2`, `stat3` would be in the same row as `rank = 1`. Something like this:

[image]

We came up with the following approach:

```
select
  a.gender
  ,a.rank
  ,b.stat1 as stat1
  ,c.stat2 as stat2
  ,d.stat3 as stat3
from stats_with_ranks as a
left join stats_with_ranks as b on a.gender = b.gender and a.rank = b.stat1rk
left join stats_with_ranks as c on a.gender = c.gender and a.rank = c.stat2rk
left join stats_with_ranks as d on a.gender = d.gender and a.rank = d.stat3rk
order by gender asc, rank asc
```

**however** this approach doesn't scale with our larger data set, where there are 200+ stats in a table that we are ranking. We very quickly get the error `Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.` when there are 200+ of these left joins. This is why we are looking for a solution that sorts within columns.

Comment: in your example some stats have int64 data type and some float64. is it possible in your use case to all stats column of the same data type? let's say float64? this would open some extra options to consider

Comment: We don't mind listing out all 200+ stats so long as the query resources aren't exceeded. `statN` is not a good assumption though. We're better off just listing out all of the various metrics.

All types are *either* int64 or float64, no other types. I believe it is better to maintain the two distinct types if possible. There also **may or may not** be nulls in the data - we can assume no nulls for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We don't mind listing out all 200+ stats so long as the query resources aren't exceeded ...

```
create temp function  extract_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as "return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));";
create temp function  extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as "return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));";
select * from (
  select gender, col, cast(stat as float64) stat, row_number() over(partition by gender, col order by cast(stat as float64) desc) rank
  from stats t, 
  unnest([struct(to_json_string((select as struct * except(gender) from unnest([t]))) as json)]),
  unnest(extract_keys(json)) col with offset
  join unnest(extract_values(json)) stat with offset
  using(offset)
)
pivot (any_value(stat) for col in ('stat1','stat2','stat3'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This seems to work just fine even with the `cast(stat as float64)` replaced with only `stat`. Keeps `int64` and `float64` and sorts correctly. Why do you think casting to float64 is `necessary`.

Comment: I think this is the better answer to accept, as real data will never have stat columns with naming convention `statN`. Thanks!

Comment: `statN` are all string-types. It would be better if columns keep their original type. I think I can cast cols back to their original type afterwards...

Comment: yes. that is why i have `cast(stat as float64) stat` in my answer. obviously this approach loses int64 and all stats become float64

Comment: Since everything is dropped into the two `col` and `stat` columns before reshaping, we lose the types for the separate columns. Makes sense. I actually love this answer because it makes use of pivot to reshape the data long --> wide. I ran the query without the `pivot` to better understand what's going on here. Really great stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Below answer assumes that all stats column are of the same data type and have naming convention as statN

```
execute immediate (select '''
  select * from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by gender, col order by stat desc) rank
    from stats
    unpivot (stat for col in (''' || col_list || ''')) 
  )
  pivot (any_value(stat) for col in (''' || val_list || '''))
  order by gender, rank
  '''
  from (
    select 
      string_agg('"stat' || pos || '"') val_list, 
      string_agg('stat' || pos) col_list
    from unnest(generate_array(1,3)) pos
  )
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question (with all float64 values)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I replied on the initial question w/ replies to your Qs. Also, what is this `execute immediate (select ''' ...`? Why not just the inner select statement?

Comment: `execute immediate` allows to dynamically build list of columns! but if you are ok with manually listing them - you can ignore it and use inner select